# In Actor Pattern (AKKA.Net) Should actors be classes OR Objects?

Tags: .net, actor-model, akka

Im Just getting started with actor pattern. Coming from `UnitOfWork` pattern.
Lets say i want to create Actor Pattern for a Employee Management System to mark they are present or absent.

The Problem Im facing is
Should I Create a class Say `EmployeesActor` instantiate it and use it as a single actor to manage all the employees. So then the messages will specify which particular employee to be marked present.
OR

Should i create a base class `EmployeeActor` and then create objects of this class for each employee in the System. This was messages would directly go to the object of `EmployeeActor`.

Comment: You already accepted an answer, so I'll just [link to this.](https://blog.jayway.com/2013/11/15/an-actor-model-implementation-in-c-using-tpl-dataflow/)  It's a sample Actor implementation in C#.  It answers your question about whether you need what amounts to a "singleton" (you don't).  *Actors are always individual instances.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to create something like EmployeesManager. As a Manager this one class particularly does not have a state but will be used to manage other actors that can have state. This will receive all messages. Once Manager receives command that a particular Employee be marked as present , it will get actor referece by providing the ID, similar to a GetByID call in DDD ( assuming you are persisting the same) and do a  actor.Tell() to send the Command to the actor reference.
(Its been a year since you posted this question. I would love to see a bigger community so newbie like me/us can get more insight)

Comment: yes is been more than a year. i tried orleans after akka then completely scrapped the idea of an actor based system. no more working on it but  will love to be part of the community. as i think actor based systems with a pre- made / open sourced actor management system can go big.